# Detecting the context for Office365 vs outlook.com

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

What is the correct way of detecting the context difference for outlook.com and Office365 accounts? I'm looking to provide some different experience per account types but I'm not sure about what's the right way. A potential solution is to check the email address and extension, but I'm looking for a more elegant (through code like: `Office.context.isO365()` ) way of solving it.

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType could be the one to resolve it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.userprofile#accounttype-string

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Would you make you comment the answer? Someone would definitely benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.userprofile#accounttype-string